# hide or show a div in specific custom taxonomy category

Tags: php, wordpress

I've created custom post type as `single-service.php` and I have several custom taxonomies under service posts like `education`, `recruit` and `health`.

I currently created some queries and under each query, I want to create a button which direct the users the contact form page of that service. It is like when you get into a single service page which is categorized under `education` there will a button directs them to education contact form page likewise for recruit page.

I have tried below link but somehow it does not work. I am not sure whether I am using correct code or where do I make mistake

```
<?php if (in_category( 'education', $post->ID )) : ?>
    <?php echo '<div class="button"><a href="#">Contact us</a></div>'; ?>

<?php elseif (in_category('recruit', $post->ID)) :?>
    <?php echo '<div class="button"><a href="#">Contact us</a></div>'; ?>

<?php elseif (in_category('health', $post->ID)) :?>
    <?php echo '<div class="button"><a href="#">Contact us</a></div>'; ?>

<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: What actually happens - you say 'it doesn't work' - what does that mean? Firstly you are missing semicolons at the end of each of the echo lines before the closing php tags. You also don't need to keep opening and closing the tags anyway if you are echoing the html

Comment: Thanks @DJC. Sorry for not being clear. Nothing appears when I apply this code. Do you have any idea why would this not work? by the way I added semicolon before the closing php tags.

Comment: Which template are you in? And are these 'categories' of the standard WP category type or are they custom taxonomies?

Comment: Hi @DJC, thanks I've already solve the problem by creating custom field in the CPT page and linking them pages. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem by creating two custom fields in the template page and linking them with :

```
  <div class="service-button">
      <?php $info = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_post_info', true); if (!$info) $info = array(); ?>
      <a class="form" style="background-color:<?php echo $info['color'] ?>" href="<?php echo $info['form'] ?>">Contact us</a>
      <?php if ($info['website']) : ?>
      <a class="website" style="background-color:<?php echo $info['color'] ?>" href="http://<?php echo $info['website'] ?>"><?php echo $info['website'] ?></a>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
```